# My app uses a lot of memory when I use imageView.layer.shouldRasterize = YES

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-graphics

My app has a UITableView and cells that contain several UIImageViews, these imageViews have the layer of shadow and cornerRadius.
In order to improve performance, I use

```
//if set to NO, tableView is slow to move
imageView.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;

//solve image become blurry problem
imageView.layer.rasterizationScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
```

But when I load many cells, it uses a lot of memory and crashes with this error:

> CGBitmapContextInfoCreate: unable to allocate 283136 bytes for bitmap data

How can I fix this?

**Edit 1**

In CAlayer.h

```
/* When true, the layer is rendered as a bitmap in its local coordinate
* space ("rasterized"), then the bitmap is composited into the
* destination (with the minificationFilter and magnificationFilter
* properties of the layer applied if the bitmap needs scaling).
* Rasterization occurs after the layer's filters and shadow effects
* are applied, but before the opacity modulation. As an implementation
* detail the rendering engine may attempt to cache and reuse the
* bitmap from one frame to the next. (Whether it does or not will have
* no affect on the rendered output.)
*
* When false the layer is composited directly into the destination
* whenever possible (however, certain features of the compositing
* model may force rasterization, e.g. adding filters).
*
* Defaults to NO. Animatable. */

@property BOOL shouldRasterize;
```

**'attempt to cache'**

I think it load images and these shadow data to memory and cause it uses a lot of memory.

[Performance scrolling and retina resolution images in CALayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4475127/performance-scrolling-and-retina-resolution-images-in-calayer)

[Drawing mask influence performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36138604/drawing-mask-influence-performance)

complete code:

```
imageView.layer.borderWidth = 0.2;
imageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.95 alpha:1].CGColor;
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 2;

imageView.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
imageView.layer.rasterizationScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];


UIView *shadowView = [[UIView alloc] init];
shadowView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

//set layer, if I don't use shadow view
shadowView.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.93 alpha:1].CGColor;
shadowView.layer.cornerRadius = 2;
shadowView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1,1);
shadowView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1;
shadowView.layer.shadowRadius = 0.6;
shadowView.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
shadowView.layer.rasterizationScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
[shadowView setFrame:containerFrame];

[shadowView addSubview:imageView];

//add shadowView to cell ...
```

Comment: Huh?  _How can I Owned fish and bear paw?_

Comment: @Avi, he mean how can he get both. Table view scrolling perfect and solve this memory crash. Own fish and bear paw (Mencius idiom)

Comment: I have literally never heard that idiom before.  Perhaps it's not the best way to phrase an SO question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add view under your imageView for shadow only and use same settings for it, but not for imageView.

Make sure 
shadowView.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
shadowView.layer.rasterizationScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
called once at cell initialization

Comment: In fact, I did it as you say.